# Null Object Error When Execute the send mail code

Tags: apex, send-email

When I am running the below code to Execute anonymous, its through the following error.

**My Code:**

```
EmailTemplate templ = [Select id,name,subject from EmailTemplate 
                                  where name ='test invoice'];

//templ return the record.

        Contact tContact  = new Contact();
        tContact.LastName ='John';
        tContact.firstName = 'Mike';
        tContact.email = 'mymail@hosting.com';
        tContact.Account = [select id, name from Account limit 1];
        Insert tContact;

  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setTemplateId(templ.id);
        email.setTargetObjectId(tContact.id);
        email.setWhatId('006fsdff000dIedE');
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);

 List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lMessgs = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        lMessgs.add(email);
        Messaging.sendEmail(lMessgs);
```

Error:

> SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, List has no rows for assignment to SObject: []

Comment: Check if there is an EmailTemplate with the name 'test invoice'. That, or that at least one Account record exists.

Comment: Yes I have test and contact is created and alos template is there. but it is through the error.

Comment: Does the OpportunityId 006fsdff000dIedE exist?

Comment: YEs it is exisit. Just copy paste the above code and try your execute annonyms. You would get the error.

Comment: I have run a modified version using execute anonymous apex (after modifying to valid Id's for my org). It completed and I received the emails (changed the contacts email address to my own). I suggest you double check all your Ids or try another EmailTemplate. It may be something that the email template is trying to do.

Comment: I have checked from my end, if i use the limti 1 in the template query it is working fine. but if I use the with name. its through error. It is the visualforce email template. when i query with name it is coming but the subject being null. is there any problem?

Comment: When I am test that vf email template via send merge field, i got the same error.

Comment: You have 2 or more EmailTemplate records with the same name.

Comment: I do not believe it has to do with the email template or the error would be getting thrown on the class name at the row for the query that is returning no rows. Since the actual method that fails is the send email method, it has to be that the opportunity ID does not exist. copy the ID of `006fsdff000dIedE` into your browser after the salesforce.com/ (i.e. salesforce.com/006fsdff000dIedE) and see if the record appears. If not then you have the ID wrong

Comment: tContact.Account = [select id, name from Account limit 1];
The problem is here. The query results in a List and you are assigning it to Sobject.

Comment: @Animesh - Actually that is perfectly acceptable. The query with a limit of 1 will assign to an sObject (If one is found)

Comment: I had the same problem. All objects existed, even the template existed, but apparently the template had a reference to a component that was somehow removed. When I re-saved the component the template worked again and the error was gone. Might help someone who is reading this!